# Does continuous retries for LAContext violates any HIG?

Tags: ios, swift, biometrics, localauthentication

1. On getting LAError.systemCancel should we call evaluatePolicy again to try max attempts ?
2. On localizedFallbackTitle should we keep it as "Try again" or "Retry" to actually call evaluatePolicy until it reaches max attempts ?

```
 if error._code == LAError.biometryLockout.rawValue {
                   // show passcode fallback 
                    return
                } else if laContext.localizedFallbackTitle == "Scan again/ Try again/ Retry" &&
                            (error._code == LAError.userFallback.rawValue ||
                                error._code == LAError.systemCancel.rawValue) {
                     // Try again until max attempts
                    return
                }
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't. System cancel means that the user cannot use local authentication right now. It doesn't make sense to retry automatically. It's better to try again at specific times, e.g. when the app returns to foreground or when user presses a button. You should generally handle system cancel like user cancel.

Comment: Does that violates any HIG ?

Comment: I don't think violation of HIG is ontopic here. If you want to check, read Apple HIG. However, note that the decision whether something violates them are often very subjective.